# How to implement cookieconsent into multilanguage prestashop?

Tags: javascript, task-parallel-library, prestashop

:)

I'd like to implement the cookie consent from insites.com into my prestashop installation. But given how it'd be a different code depending on the selected language, I'm curious if it's possible to load different head.tpl files based on the selected language

Answer (score 0):

You can display a different script depending on language:

```
{if $language.language_code == 'en'}
    //script for EN
{elseif $language.language_code == 'es'}
    //script for ES
....
{/if}
```